# CORS with jQuery.ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, xmlhttprequest, cors

Firefox seems to be preventing this request, while Chrome is processing it fine.  What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/e8qu2g9j/1/

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json",
    data: {
        bounds: "-35.2545,149.4947|-31.9955,152.5728",
        region: "au",
        components: "country:AU|administrative_area:NSW",
        address: "Central Station"
    }
});
```

I've tried adding:

```js
crossDomain: true,
xhrFields: {
    mozAnon: true,
    mozSystem: true
},
```

but to no avail.

Firefox 31.0 keeps giving me:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?bounds=-35.2545%2C149.4947%7C-31.9955%2C152.5728&region=au&components=country%3AAU%7Cadministrative_area%3ANSW&address=Central+Station. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

**EDIT:** This is working fine for me in a new firefox profile, but not my main one.  What setting could I have changed?

Comment: are you calling the google maps in https?

Comment: no.  google says i may use http: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests

Comment: {"results":[{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Central Station","short_name":"Central Station","types":["train_station","transit_station","establishment"]},{"long_name":"Haymarket","short_name":"Haymarket","types":

Comment: add this on xhrFields
`xhrFields: {
       withCredentials: true //or try it to false
    }`

Comment: on my side it is working fine in fiddle

Comment: `withCredentials` (either `true` or `false`) is not working for me.

Comment: so it is something specific to my firefox?  i will try a new profile.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the HTTPS everywhere plugin.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=692843